# Function callers across multiple functions

Tags: c++

I have an assignment in which, I am to make two separate functions from int main().  The first one is to be a void function, which is prompt for and receives 3 integers, which it returns to the caller..  The second function is to be a value return function, and it receives values from the caller and performs various mathematical applications to said values, returning the result.

The functions can't be invoked from within each other, they must be invoked in main.  The code I posted compiles, and does what it's intended to, but the instructor wants it to be done the way they specified with the callers.  I am not sure what is mean by this.  I assume the callers are the () part of a function, but for some reason I can't get different variations of that to compile without it saying something or other is out of scope...  How can I get this to run the way specified?  If I can, I will attach the homework file for reference.  Thanks in advance for any advice!

This code is being compiled on a school computer which runs on Unix.  I have got it to compile, and the way I originally wrote it was syntactically correct and produced a correct result, however, the instructor wants the code written differently and I am not understanding.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int num_1, num_2, num_3;

int main()
{
    void prompter();
    int results();
    prompter();
    cout << "Result: " << results() << endl;

    return 0;
}

void prompter()

{
    cout << "Enter in three integers: " << endl;

    cin >> num_1 >> num_2 >> num_3;

}

int results()
{
    int first_Sum;

    int second_Sum;

    int final_Sum;

    first_Sum = (num_1 + num_2)*num_3;

    second_Sum = (num_2 + num_3)*num_1;

    final_Sum = first_Sum + second_Sum;

    return final_Sum;
}
```

The output is correct, but my method is not.  How can I achieve the results of this code but by using function callers?

Comment: Part 1: Assignment5 setup 1. Open a terminal window and make sure it is in your home directory. 2. Change directories into  LabComp/Assignment5 – this directory was created in the first Lab Comprehension Assignment.3. Use gedit to edit a new file called Assignment5.cpp4. All output statements are to end with a line termination (i.e. << endl or << “\n” )

Comment: It's pretty hard to guess what your instructor meant, but my first thought was to use *output arguments* in `prompter`, not global variables.

Comment: Part 2: Content for program Assignment5.cpp 1.  In this program all function calls occur within main.  The functions you write cannot call another function.2.  Write a program that contains a value returning function and a void function. 3. The void function is to prompt for and read in three integers.  These integer values are returned to the caller of the function.   4. The value returning function(cannot use reference parameters) is to receive three integer values from the caller and perform the following actions on those three integer values:

Comment: a.  Add the first and second integers and multiply the sum by the third integer. b.  Add the second and third integers and multiply the sum by the first integer. c.   Add together the results from parts a and b and return the integer value to the caller of the function. 5.  In main: declare a minimum of three integer variables. 6.  In main call the void function described above to obtain three integer values. 7.  In main call the value returning function described above to generate the return value. 8.

Comment: 9.  Once your program compiles and runs, submit it through Canvas to Assignment5  10. Sample output of a run from my solution: blackhawk> ./a.out  Enter in three integers:  4   5   6            Result: 98

Comment: Ok so all my comments are basically the assignment info.  Sorry, I didn't know there wasn't a way to upload it or I would have went into more detail in the actual question.

Comment: You could [edit] your question instead... And 75% of it is not relevant to your question anyway.

Comment: You have recently learned about reference parameters. Read about them some more.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sorry, this is my first time on stack overflow.  I was just hoping to get some clarity on the topic.  There must be something I'm missing because the instructions don't make sense to me.